# Parsing jsonlines column into datafarme in R results in trailing garbage error

Tags: r, json, jsonlines

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is in jsonlines format (I think) and i can't manage to parse it and have tried a few different methods but end up with a trailing garbage error. Has anyone dealt with this before? I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
library(tidyjson)
ff <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaydenSchilling/Example_code_and_data/master/testjson.csv")
ff

json_as_df <- ff %>% as.tbl_json(json.column = "EffortData")
```

results in:

```
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
                                    "{"BoatUnit": "BFM", "Electrofishi
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: Looking at your raw data - `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaydenSchilling/Example_code_and_data/master/testjson.csv` - there appear to be extra quotes `"` around each string. This is probably your issue.

Comment: Thanks - good spotting. It seems load into R without these though. A previous version did load with all the extra quotation marks but i replaced all the doubles with single quotation marks and thought i had fixed that.


`head(ff,1)
                                                                                                                                                                                                           EffortData
1 "{"BoatUnit": "BFM", "ElectrofishingDuration": 90, "SubmergedLight": false}"
  EffortPageLetter
1                A`